# Storing session inside partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write an ASP.NET MVC application which links a person's relation to other members of the family.

I am trying to implement the following screen:

[image]

Where each member is implemented via a bootstrap tab, so far I am able to navigate between tabs based on dynamically generated id(s).

View markup:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

@using HouseHolderInfoSystem.Entity.Models

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    // Navigation click handler
    $(".relation_link").click(function(event) {

      //Get the ID
      const memberId = $(this).attr("data-memberId");

      // AJAX call to get the partial view content
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "DisplayRelationTagger")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
          MemberId: memberId,
          ApplicationId: '@ViewBag.ApplicationId'
        }),
        success: function(data) {
          //populate the tab content.
          $(`#${memberId}`).html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.error('Could not update the div because of some error!');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<br />

<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Household Relationships</h2>
            <br>
            <h4>
                Please tell us how the members of your household are related to each other
            </h4>

            <hr>
            <br>

            @if (ViewBag.FamilyMembers != null)
            {
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    @for (int i = 0, familyMembersCount = (ViewBag.FamilyMembers as List<FamilyMember>).Count; i < familyMembersCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            <li class="active">
                                <a data-toggle="tab" class="relation_link" data-memberId="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FamilyMemberId))" href="#@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FamilyMemberId))"> @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FirstName)) @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).LastName)) </a>
                            </li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="tab" class="relation_link" data-memberId="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FamilyMemberId))" href="#@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FamilyMemberId))"> @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FirstName)) @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).LastName)) </a>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content">
                    @for (int i = 0, familyMembersCount = (ViewBag.FamilyMembers as List<FamilyMember>).Count; i < familyMembersCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            <div id="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FamilyMemberId))" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                @(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FirstName)) @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).LastName))
                            </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div id="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FamilyMemberId))" class="tab-pane fade">
                                @(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).FirstName)) @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.FamilyMembers[i] as FamilyMember).LastName))
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            }
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    @Html.RouteLink("Back", "", null, new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-danger" })
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    @Html.RouteLink("Save and submit", "", null, new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary" })
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

Partial view code:

```
@using HouseHolderInfoSystem.Entity.Models

<script>
        function ChangeRelationSelection(CurrentMemberId, RelatedFamilyMemberId, Relation ) {
            if ( !CurrentMemberId || !RelatedFamilyMemberId || !Relation )
            {
                alert( `Current member ID or Related member ID or Relation cannot be empty!` );
                return;
            }


            const url = `@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "UpdateRelationTagging")`;
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify( { FamilyMemberId: CurrentMemberId, RelatedFamilyMemberId: RelatedFamilyMemberId, Relation: Relation } ),
            };

            fetch( url, options )
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then( data => console.log(data.message))
                .catch(error => console.error( error.message ));
        }



</script>

@if (ViewBag.CurrentMember != null && ViewBag.RemainingMembers != null)
{
    <br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Relationships of @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.CurrentMember as FamilyMember).FirstName)) @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((ViewBag.CurrentMember as FamilyMember).LastName))</legend>


        @foreach (FamilyMember familyMember in (List<FamilyMember>)ViewBag.RemainingMembers)
        {
            <div style="display:block" class="form-group">
                <span style="color:red; font-size:16px;">* </span>
                <span>
                    Relationship to @(Html.AttributeEncode((familyMember as FamilyMember).FirstName)) @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode((familyMember as FamilyMember).LastName))
                </span>
                <select id='@(Html.AttributeEncode(familyMember.FamilyMemberId))' class="form-control relationSelect" onchange="ChangeRelationSelection('@(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.CurrentMemberId))', '@(Html.AttributeEncode(familyMember.FamilyMemberId))', event.currentTarget.value)">
                    <option selected disabled>----Please select a relation----</option>
                    <option value="Father">Father</option>
                    <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                    <option value="Son">Son</option>
                    <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                    <option value="Husband">Husband</option>
                    <option value="Wife">Wife</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
        }
    </fieldset>

}
```

C# controller code:

```
[Route("tag-relations/{ApplicationId:guid}", Name = "TagRelationGet")]
public ActionResult TagRelations(string ApplicationId)
{
    Application currentApplication = _applicationService.GetApplicationById(ApplicationId);
    ViewBag.FamilyMembers = currentApplication.FamilyMembersApplication.ToList();
    ViewBag.ApplicationId = ApplicationId;
    return View();
}

 [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/display-relations", Name = "DisplayRelationTagger")]
        public PartialViewResult DisplayRelationTagging(RelationTaggingDTO TaggingDTO)
        {
            Application currentApplication = _applicationService.GetApplicationById(TaggingDTO.ApplicationId);

            FamilyMember currentlySelectedFamilyMember = currentApplication.FamilyMembersApplication.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FamilyMemberId == TaggingDTO.FamilyMemberId);
            List<FamilyMember> remainingFamilyMembers = currentApplication.FamilyMembersApplication.Where(x => x.FamilyMemberId != TaggingDTO.FamilyMemberId).ToList();

            // Store family member member count into session for later use
            Session["FamilyMemberCount"] = currentApplication.FamilyMembersApplication.ToList().Count;

            ViewBag.CurrentApplicationId = TaggingDTO.ApplicationId;
            ViewBag.CurrentMemberId = TaggingDTO.FamilyMemberId;
            ViewBag.CurrentMember = currentlySelectedFamilyMember;
            ViewBag.RemainingMembers = remainingFamilyMembers;

            if (Session["RelationTagging"] != null)
            {
                List<UpdateRelationTaggingDTO> allRelations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UpdateRelationTaggingDTO>>(Session["RelationTagging"].ToString());

                List<UpdateRelationTaggingDTO> currentlySelectedRelations = new List<UpdateRelationTaggingDTO>();

                foreach (var item in allRelations)
                    foreach (var innerItem in remainingFamilyMembers)
                        if (item.RelatedFamilyMemberId == innerItem.FamilyMemberId)
                            currentlySelectedRelations.Add(item);

                if (currentlySelectedRelations.Count > 0)
                    ViewBag.TaggedRelationMembers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentlySelectedRelations);
            }

            return PartialView("DisplayRelationshipTagger");
        }
```

I know I have to partial view inside the tab content and call it using ajax, but my question is two-fold.

1. Let's say when I click on tab 1 which has person 1, I need to show all the members in the form except the current person which are Person 2 and Person 3.

   [image]
2. How to store the relationships inside the session so that it can be only submitted once to the database after finishing all the relationship tagging.

Comment: @marc_s well what do you think?

Comment: Can you share the partial view's html too ? what you can do is to trigger a change event on the dropdowns. and use ajax to add it to a session.

Comment: @zetawars I have added more question details, and the way which I have tried

Comment: Are you also, unable to show the Person 1 and Person 2? (i.e Question 1)?

Comment: @zetawars yeah I am unable to show

Comment: "I need to show all the members in the form except the current person which are Person 2 and Person 3." 
Are you unable to show the RamainingMembers ?


@foreach (FamilyMember familyMember in (List<FamilyMember>)ViewBag.RemainingMembers)

Answer (score 4):

What you can do in the code is to use Jquery in your main page

IF this is your current Select Statement

```
<select id='@(Html.AttributeEncode(familyMember.FamilyMemberId))' class="form-control relationSelect" onchange="ChangeRelationSelection('@(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.CurrentMemberId))', '@(Html.AttributeEncode(familyMember.FamilyMemberId))', event.currentTarget.value)">
                    <option selected disabled>----Please select a relation----</option>
                    <option value="Father">Father</option>
                    <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                    <option value="Son">Son</option>
                    <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                    <option value="Husband">Husband</option>
                    <option value="Wife">Wife</option>
                </select>
```

You can add More Attributes in a "data" attributes like

```
<select id='@(Html.AttributeEncode(familyMember.FamilyMemberId))' **data-familyid="@(Html.AttributeEncode(familyMember.FamilyMemberId))"
 data-memberid="@(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.CurrentMember.Id))"**
  class="form-control relationSelect" onchange="ChangeRelationSelection('@(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.CurrentMemberId))', '@(Html.AttributeEncode(familyMember.FamilyMemberId))', event.currentTarget.value)">
                    <option selected disabled>----Please select a relation----</option>
                    <option value="Father">Father</option>
                    <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                    <option value="Son">Son</option>
                    <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                    <option value="Husband">Husband</option>
                    <option value="Wife">Wife</option>
                </select>
```

Once you have both IDs available (i.e the CurrentMemberID and the FamilyMemberID on the Dropdown)

Next what you can do is

```
$(".relationSelect").change(function(){
//Here what you can do is read the data attributes
var familyid = $(this).data("familyid");
var MemberId = $(this).data("memberid");
var relation = $(this).val();
 // Next step is to send it via tha ajax to server and store it in the session, as you require 
$.post("@Url.Action("StoreInSession", "Controller")", {MemberID: MemberId, familyID :familyid, relation : relation}, function(resp){

});
```

Next Part in the Controller you can have a Model that can store the data in this format

```
public class RelationStore 
{
    public string MemberID {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string,string> RelationAndFamily {get;set;}
}
```

and In Controller

```
public JsonResult(string FamilyId, string memberId, string Relation )
{
    List<RelationStore> I = Session("RelationStore") as List<RelationStore>;
    //Make your Logic to Add to the List and then put the list back in session 
}
```

Comment: if the data is not sensitive, these selected values can be stored in a javascript object and on the final submit these can be sent to controller. The solution you have provided is the best questioner can do.